# Unable to install react native android apk

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I generated the signed android apk from my react-native project. Whenever I try to install it, it shows 'App Not Installed' in any of the devices I tried.

I have added all the configurations:

**build.gradle (in android dir)**
[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:largeHeap="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**build.gradle(android/app/)**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.biassure"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
    signingConfigs {
    release {
        if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
            storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
        }

    }
```

I even cleaned the gradle and re-installed node_modules. Please help to fix the problem.

Comment: can you share full error message?

Comment: it might me because device is not connected or permission is or given

Comment: How are you installing? Can you post the result from `adb install /path/to/apk` there should be details on why it's not installing there.